# Convert from Realm Results to Array produce empty objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, type-conversion, realm

When I try to convert from Results to Swift Array the properties are on the default values.

So let's say I write a `Request` object like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(request, update: true)
}
```

Then when I'm reading them from Realm like this:

```
 let realm = try! Realm()
 let requestsFromRealm = realm.objects(Request.self)
```

I got the results just fine. I need to convert the Results object to Array. I did it:

```
let requests = Array(requestsFromRealm)
```

The requests objects are there, but the properties are on the default values. The weird thing is, when I check the values on the console with `po` I can see them.

Comment: Aren't you just running into https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-object-setters-and-getters-cannot-be-overriden? So if you use the accessor, then the value is just fine?

Comment: Yes, probably... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let requestsFromRealm = realm.objects(Request.self)
let requests = requestsFromRealm.toArray()
```

Using this extension:

```
extension Results {

    func toArray() -> [T] {
        var array = [T]()
        for result in self {
            array.append(result)
        }
        return array
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let requests = Array (requestsFromRealm)
```

I think that there is no problem with this code.

Is not "dynamic" missing in the property of Realm Object?

```
class Request: Object {
     dynamic var body: String = ""
}
```