# Swif'ts Array to Realm's Result

Tags: arrays, swift, type-conversion, realm

I am trying to convert Swift `[Object]()` array to Realm's `Results<Object>!`. I know that vice-versa is possible (you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786859/convert-from-realm-results-to-array-produce-empty-objects)) but is it possible to do what I want?

So I want something like `result as! [Object]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Result` objects are proxies for data stored in the db. You can only get them via queries, but cannot instantiate them yourself (see the [docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html)).

To still get `Result` objects, you'd have to run a new query for the objects you already have, and use the returned `Result`... I would not suggest that though.

Comment: Why you don't you suggest the not suggested way?

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp because it seems to me like a misuse of the API... you already have your objects but run another query just to get them in the format of the framework. I assume you need to do that because you already have a custom API which takes `Result` and want to reuse it; I'd rather suggest to change that API to consume model objects.

Comment: Ohh, you are absolutely right about that. Thank you for explaining.